# Assign different group id to different consumers in the same application

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am aware of the parallelism advantages that kafka streams offer which are leveraged if your parallelism needs are aligned with the partitioning of the topics.

I am considering having an application subscribe many consumers to different consumer groups so that each consumer is consuming a replication of the whole topic.

Specifically I am thinking of having multiple threads consume the same topic to provide different results even though I know that I can express all my computation needs using the "chaining" computation paradigm that `KStreams` offer.

The reason why I am considering different threads is because I want multiple dynamically created `KTable` instances of the stream. Each one working on the same stream (not subset) and aggregating different results. Since it's dynamic it can create really heavy load that could be alleviated by adding thread parallelism. I believe the idea that each thread can work on its own streams instance (and consumer group) is valid.

Of course I can also add thread parallelism by having multiple threads consuming smaller subsets of the data and individually doing all the computations (e.g. each one maintaining subsets of all the different `KTables`) which will still provide concurrency.

So, two main points in my question

- Are `KafkaStreams` not generally suited for thread parallelism, meaning is the library not intended to be used that way?
- In the case where threads are being used to consume a topic would it be a better idea to make threads follow the general kafka parallelism concept of working on different subsets of the data, therefore making thread parallelism an application-level analogous to scaling up using more instances?

Comment: Looking at your question (incl. update) and @michael-g-noll answer I am still not sure what you actually try to do, and what the issues is... I think the answer gives good pointers, but you did not accept it, thus I think you have still open questions. Maybe it would be easier to discuss on Kafka mailing list: http://kafka.apache.org/contact

Comment: `KafkaStreams` is multi-threaded but it scales via partitions, not topics. Using multiple threads within a `KafkaStreams` instance is equivalent to create multiple `KafkaStreams` instances (using the same topology): cf http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html#parallelism-model

Answer (score 4):

> But I am wondering would it be okay to have an application that subscribes many consumers to different consumer groups so that each consumer is consuming a replication of the whole topic.

What you could consider is running multiple `KafkaStreams` instances inside the same Java application.  Each instance has its own `StreamsConfig` and thus its own `application.id` and consumer group id.

That said, depending on what your use case is, you might want to take a look at `GlobalKTable` (http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html#globalktable), which (slightly simplified) ensures that the data it reads from a Kafka topic is available in all instances of your Kafka Streams application.  That is, this would allow you to "replicate the data globally" without having to run multiple `KafkaStreams` instances or the more complicated setup you asked about above.

> Specifically I am considering having multiple threads consume the same topic to provide different kinds of results. Can I somehow define the consumer group that each KafkaStream consumer is listening to?

Hmm, perhaps you're looking at something else then.

You are aware that you can build multiple "chains" of computation from the same `KStream` and `KTable` instance?

```
KStream<String, Long> input = ...;
KTable<..., ...> firstChain = input.filter(...).groupByKey().count(...);
KTable<..., ...> secondChain = input.mapValues(...);
```

This would allow you to read a Kafka topic once but then compute different outcomes based on that topic.

> Is this considered a bad idea in general?

If I understand you correctly I think there's a better and much simpler approach, see above.  If you need something different, you may need to update/clarify your question.

Hope this helps!